# How to remove a certain character after the extraction of a part, using python

Tags: python

I have text file, which looks like this:

```
.
.
.
-----------------------
first ATOMIC CHARGES
-----------------------
   0 C :   -0.157853
   1 C :   -0.156875
   2 C :   -0.143714
   3 C :   -0.140489
   4 S :    0.058926
   5 H :    0.128758
   6 H :    0.128814
   7 H :    0.142420
   8 H :    0.140013
My charges :   -0.0000000

------------------------
.
..
.
```

I used this script below in order to extract a specific part.

```
with open('FILE.txt', 'rb') as f:
     textfile_temp = f.read()

     print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES')[1].split("My charges :   -0.0000000")[0]
```

my output is:

```
-----------------------
   0 C :   -0.157853
   1 C :   -0.156875
   2 C :   -0.143714
   3 C :   -0.140489
   4 S :    0.058926
   5 H :    0.128758
   6 H :    0.128814
   7 H :    0.142420
   8 H :    0.140013
```

my goal is to remove the "-----------------------" character, and my output will be like this:

```
   0 C :   -0.157853
   1 C :   -0.156875
   2 C :   -0.143714
   3 C :   -0.140489
   4 S :    0.058926
   5 H :    0.128758
   6 H :    0.128814
   7 H :    0.142420
   8 H :    0.140013
```

Comment: Do you need a single string with newline characters in it, or would a list of strings work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of that line, try:

```
stringy = stringy.replace("--", "").strip() # assuming an even number of dashes
```

This will get rid of all the extra dashes and the newline.

Or you could break the stringy into a list of lines, then exclude the first line, with

```
stringy = '\n'.join(stringy.splitlines()[1:])
```

or brute force:

```
stringy = stringy.replace('-----------------------\n', '')
```

Or just change:

```
print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES')[1].split("My charges :   -0.0000000")[0]
```

to

```
print textfile_temp.split('first ATOMIC CHARGES')[1].split("My charges :   -0.0000000")[0].replace('-----------------------\n', '')
```

Comment: HI , where can I put this line

Comment: Instead of just printing the output of the split() command, save the output to a variable. Then process the variable as above, then print the variable.

Comment: OK, I understood

Comment: I just changed the answer to show the simple way.  If my answer solves your problem, please select it as the correct answer. Happy coding!

Comment: I am very happy, thank you very much....a very simple and effective method.

Answer (score 1):

Using triple '

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    textfile_temp = f.read()

    print(textfile_temp.split('''first ATOMIC CHARGES
-----------------------''')[1].split('My charges :   -0.0000000')[0])
```

Comment: A very very interesting method, thank you. **"correct result"**

Answer (score 1):

@Hamza allal In this, simplest you can just find two indexes from the file data,

1. First occurrence of `0` number
2. Index of ' My charges' string

`zero_ind = file_data.find("0")`

`str_ind = file_data.find("My charges", zero_ind)`

`file_data[zero_ind:str_ind].split("\n")`

Then just split the file data using '\n' you will get all items you want.